# How To Mask SQL Pivot Null Result as Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPresentStock](
    [sProductName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [sStockistName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [sDivision] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image]

[image]

The below query is working fine except the Null result.

I would like to replace the Null Results with 0.

```
/* COLUMNS HEADERS */
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @columnHeaders  = COALESCE (@columnHeaders   
+ ',[' + sStockistName + ']', '[' + sStockistName + ']')
FROM   TblPresentStock  
GROUP BY sStockistName
ORDER BY sStockistName


/* GRAND TOTAL COLUMN */
DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (sStockistName AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM     TblPresentStock
  GROUP BY sStockistName
  ORDER BY sStockistName
 SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

/* GRAND TOTAL ROW */
DECLARE @GrandTotalRow  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
FROM     TblPresentStock
    GROUP BY sStockistName
  ORDER BY  sStockistName
----------------------------------------------

 -- DROP TABLE  temp_MatchesTotal

/* MAIN QUERY */
DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') 
AS [Grand Total] INTO  #temp_MatchesTotal
            FROM
                (SELECT sProductName,sDivision,sStockistName,Qty
                    FROM  TblPresentStock
                ) A
            PIVOT
                (
                 sum (Qty)
                 FOR sStockistName
                 IN ('  +@columnHeaders +  ')
                ) B
ORDER BY sProductName,sDivision
SELECT * FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal UNION ALL
SELECT ''Grand Total'','''','+@GrandTotalRow +',  
ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal
  DROP TABLE  #temp_MatchesTotal'
 -- PRINT 'Pivot Query '+@FinalQuery
 -- SELECT @FinalQuery
 EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)
```

[image]

Any suggestion will be highly helpful.

---

> @Sixthsense Could you please shown only the GrandTotalCol string? I
>   want to see what's the exact SQL build there. – gotqn

**Row And Column Grand Total Query**

```
SELECT COALESCE(',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
as 'Row Grand Total Result ',

COALESCE ('ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (sStockistName AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
as 'Column Grand Total Result'

FROM TblPresentStock
```

**Result of the above query**

### [image]

Comment: Are you looking for `MAX()` for dynamic columns?

Comment: Everything is working fine.  I just want to show 0 instead of Null.  If you see the last pic then you can see Null value in the result.

Comment: @Sixthsense Could you please shown only the `GrandTotalCol` string? I want to see what's the exact SQL build there.

Comment: @ gotqn, updated the post which shows the GrandTotalCol string for your reference.

Comment: Can you able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null values appears only in query results but when it is applied in gridview it shows blank (as intended).

How silly it is... :)

Answer (score 0):

Final output control is achieved in the outermost select clause. e.g.

```
SELECT COALESCE(some_number,0) AS x
```

It is no different in a pivot query, except now the pivot query is producing new column names. You have to list each one of those new column names into the outermost select clause and use `COALESCE()` (or `ISNULL`) on each one of these. e.g.

```
SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *
  , COALESCE(' + GrandTotalCol1 + ',0) 
  , COALESCE(' + GrandTotalCol2 + ',0) 
...
  , COALESCE(' + GrandTotalCol12 + ',0) 
...
```

For dynamically produced pivot SQL this may require 2 sets of strings of the generated columns, one to use with the `IN(....)` and another for the outermost select clause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I added the pics for your easy reference.  Can you please go through it and suggest me your valuable inputs?